# Select multiple options in a collection_select rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know how to put together a simple select box that takes its values from a model

```
<%= f.collection_select(:sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please Select a Sector") %>
```

My question is how do i allow a user to select multiple options and then store them in the model. I know i need to use

```
:multiple => true
```

But unsure on the syntax

Usually for multiple entries to a model i would use accepts_nested_attributes_for but am i correct in thinking i don't need to for this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Ok after some trial and error

```
<%= f.collection_select(:sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Please Select a Sector"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

lets me select multiple options

Answer (score -1):

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

The things that go in the options hash are described at the top of the page, and include :prompt.  The html_options hash is for html attributes that you want to set, e.g. multiple, a class, an id.