# How do I create a multiple item select list in Rails from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code - it's working fine but I want to be able to select multiple Organisations, while this select only allows me to choose one.

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, 
                        Organisation.order(:Company_Name), 
                        :id, 
                        :Company_Name, 
                        options = {include_blank: "Select an Organisation"}, 
                        html_options = {:onchange => 'broadcast_dropdown_change(document.getElementById("broadcast_country_id"), document.getElementById("broadcast_organisation_id"))'} %>
```

Please help me resolve this, along with any advice on how I  can improve this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select multiple options in a collection\_select rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074710/select-multiple-options-in-a-collection-select-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add the html option `multiple: true` :) Hopefully that'll do it, nice and easily!

If not, you'll need to ensure the permitted parameters match up to what's getting passed through - likely a JSON encoded array of options - and parse / save them as appropriate in the database.

Couple more examples available in the duplicate I've linked in the comment to your post. Let me know how you get on and I'll provide a little more info if need be!

---

Update based on your comment, here's an example:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, 
                        Organisation.order(:Company_Name), 
                        :id, 
                        :Company_Name, 
                        { include_blank: "Select an Organisation" }, 
                        onchange: 'broadcast_dropdown_change(document.getElementById("broadcas‌​t_country_id"), document.getElementById("broadcast_organisation_id")', 
                        multiple: true %>
```

Couple of notes here:

- the last two arguments this method takes are for `options` and `html_options`; the `include_blank: ...` is in the former, and the final two arguments the latter
- you don't need to assign these hashes to variables. The first hash needs the brackets to distinguish it from the second, though the final hash is implicit so doesn't require the brackets (though you can use them, if you find it easier to read, i.e.)

  ```
  { onchange: 'broadcast_dropdown_change(document.getElementById("broadcas‌​t_country_id"), document.getElementById("broadcast_organisation_id")', 
    multiple: true }
  ```
- have a quick look at how you're naming your variables - it's worth spending the time to format them correctly - for example, `:Company_Name` should always be lower snake case `:company_name`

Hope that helps - again, give me a shout and let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I can't  seem to  get it right with this one, where do I add `multiple: true` in this code, when I add it like  its shown on the link you posted I get an error, 

`<%= f.collection_select :id, Organisation.order(:Company_Name), :id, :Company_Name, options = {include_blank: "Select an Organisation"}, html_options = {:onchange => 'broadcast_dropdown_change(document.getElementById("broadcast_country_id"), document.getElementById("broadcast_organisation_id"), {:multiple => true})'}  %>` 

Like this it doesn't allow me to select multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the update @MrNash - take a look at my updated answer. You're almost there with this, just a couple of tweaks needed :) Any questions, let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much that worked @SRack I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome @MrNash - glad to help out :) Feel free to accept the answer if it's solved the problem...